# Absolute value in rational numbers

Tags: calculus, absolute-value, rational-numbers

We define the absolute value in $\mathbb{Q}$ as an application $||\, \cdot \, || : \mathbb{Q}\rightarrow [0,\infty )$ that fulfills the properties:

- $||x||=0$ if and only if $x=0$.
- $||xy||=||x||\, ||y||$.
- $||x+y||\leq ||x||+||y||.$

We have to show that if for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ we have $||n||\leq 1$, then it is fulfilled that for all $x,y\in \mathbb{Q}$ we have
$$||x+y||\leq \max (||x||, ||y||).$$

My attempt is as follows:

$$||x+y||^N =\prod_{i=1}^N ||x+y|| =||(x+y)^N||=|| \sum_{k=0}^N {N\choose k}x^{N-k}y^k|| \leq \sum_{k=0}^N ||{N\choose k}x^{N-k}y^k||$$

Can you help me doing this proof?

Thanks

Comment: That's not true: $||1+1||=2 > 1=||1||.$

Comment: You'll get some useful ideas [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrowski%27s_theorem#Case_II:_%E2%88%80n_%E2%88%88_N_|n|%E2%88%97_%E2%89%A4_1).

Comment: Something seems jumbled about your problem statement.  In particular when you reach the part "We have to show...", you put a condition on all (?) integers $n$ that $||n||\le 1$.  So this is not satisfied by the usual "absolute value" on rational numbers.  It might be clearer if you gave an explicit function satisfying your properties.

Comment: It isn't the usual absolute value. The absolute value is defined with the three properties given and nothing more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Q}^2$, you have
$$ \|x+y\|^n=\|(x+y)^n|\|=\left\|\sum_{k=0}^n{\binom{n}{k}x^k y^{n-k}} \right\|\leqslant\sum_{k=0}^n{\underbrace{\left\|\binom{n}{k}\right\|}_{\leqslant 1}\|x^k y^{n-k}\|}\leqslant\sum_{k=0}^n{\|x\|^k\|y\|^{n-k}} $$
Since $\|x\|\leqslant\|\max(x,y)\|$ and $\|y\|\leqslant \|\max(x,y)\|$ you then have
$$\|x+y\|^n\leqslant\sum_{k=0}^n{\|\max(x,y)\|^k\|\max(x,y)\|^{n-k}}=(n+1)\|\max(x,y)\|^n $$
Hence
$$ \|x+y\|\leqslant (n+1)^{\frac{1}{n}}\|\max(x,y)\|\underset{n\rightarrow +\infty}{\longrightarrow}\|\max(x,y)\| $$

Comment: Why is the absolute value of the combinatorial number less than or equal to 1?

Comment: Because $\binom{n}{k}\in\mathbb{Z}$, thus $\left\|\binom{n}{k}\right\|\leqslant 1$.